# How do I customize the FileOpen dialog for >= Vista?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, windows-7, openfiledialog

I'm looking to customize the Vista-like `OpenFileDialog` with custom WinForms and WPF controls.  I know you can template the [XP-like OpenFileDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy) but that looks pretty ugly and doesn't satisfy my requirements.  I know you can customize the `OpenFileDialog` with either the [Ookii](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs) dialogs or from [Microsoft's API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).  The problem with this approach is that they don't allow for custom controls, only a limited subset of controls (`Label`, `TextBox`, etc.).

The closest I've gotten is the below image.  Using a combination of the API Code Pack, some changes to the Shell, a hack-job of adding empty labels for the spacing, with a bunch of ugly COM to draw the control directly on the OpenFileDialog I was able to get close.

The problem with this approach is that I have to disable re-sizing in the WndProc because the controls section in the `CommonOpenFileDialog` has a flow/wrap layout and you can't dynamically add/remove controls on re-size or you get a catastrophic failure if the OpenFileDialog has already been shown.

Are there any suggestions beyond what I have tried or any third-party products that work as the standard Vista-like OpenFileDialog but allow for insertion of custom controls?

[[image]

I also tried rolling my own using the ExplorerBrowser from the API Code Pack (as in the image below) but despite combing over the COM API there doesn't seem like a way to define filters in the ExplorerBrowser.

[[image]

Comment: IFileDialogCustomize supports plenty of doodahs.  But it is not infinitely extensible and you don't have the flexibility you are probably looking for.  Nor is it possible to bolt on something completely new.  Nothing you can do but settle for what is supported.

Comment: **Why** are you trying to "customize the FileOpen dialog"? What are your "custom controls" going to be doing?

Comment: @DourHighArch - I want to add a thumbnail filmstrip as shown in the first image but for a custom file type.  There needs to be additional data that will be contained within a tool tip.  There are also some configuration parameters that users can optionally define that affect how the thumbnails are rendered.  It's not merely a matter of setting up IPreviewHandler for the file type.

Comment: Why not design the dialog from scratch?

Comment: This guy created a treeview directory. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OwyNiLPDNw&list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M&index=2 


It can give you some hints to create your own OpenFileDialog.

Comment: Take a look at this CodeProject article [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42008/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-Using-WPF)

Comment: If you're willing to pay a bit, Telerik may have the WPF controls you want in their RadControl for WPF. See https://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/file-dialogs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing can easily be written from scratch using WPF and XAML.  If necessary, there are controls for easy sub component you want.

If you try to modify an existing file dialog, you'll be limited and may hit a brick wall later on.

Comment: @Paul_Sumpner: It would be helpful to provide some sample code, wouldn't it?